# for(i) not iterating over querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, custom-data-attribute, selectors-api

I try to iterate through `querySelectorAll()` and get their `data-` values (I feel like I didn't explained it well so I hope that the code below will be more helpful for me to explain what I mean):

```
<input type="text" id="data-element" placeholder="Insert value here" readonly />
<a href="javascript:" data-element data-element-value="Value 1">Click me to set value</a>
<a href="javascript:" data-element data-element-value="Value 2">Click me to change the current value</a>
```

---

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.querySelector('body').onclick = function() {
        if(document.getElementById('data-element') !== null) {
            var output  = document.getElementById('data-element');
            var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-element]');
            for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
                anchors[i].onclick = function() {
                    output.value = anchors[i].getAttribute('data-element-value');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I need to output the value of each `[data-element-value]` where `[data-element]` is not null (or: exists) into `#data-element` (or: `id="data-element"`)

as you can see, it doesn't work... how can I solve this?

Comment: In your case, the really easy fix is to change `output.value = anchors[i].getAttribute(...);` to `output.value = this.getAttribute(...);` The linked question's answers explain why it wasn't working (the value of `i` was not what you thought it was as of when the click occurred).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much! :)